# Index match formula with duplicate value

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match, vlookup

I have an excel index/match formula (see below) but my data contains duplicate values therefore excel only returns the first value. Is there a way to modify my formula below to return to the nth value?

```
=IF(B24>='3. Lookups'!CU:CU, INDEX('3. Lookups'!CZ:CZ, MATCH(AC24, '3. Lookups'!CT:CT,0)), "blank")
```

Comment: Add a helper column to generate a unique id? You can use Countif for that e.g. https://exceljet.net/formula/get-nth-match-with-vlookup

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this for the INDEX part. This will return the second value. For the Nth value, adjust the last parameter in the formula.

```
=INDEX('3. Lookups'!CZ:CZ,SMALL(IF('3. Lookups'!CT:CT=AC24,ROW('3. Lookups'!CT:CT)-ROW(INDEX('3. Lookups'!CT:CT,1,1))+1),2))
```

It's an array-formula, so use `Ctrl + Shift + Enter` to confirm,

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
=iferror(index('3. Lookups'!CZ:CZ, aggregate(15, 7, row(a:a)/('3. Lookups'!CT$1:CT$9999=AC24), nth)), "blank")
```

Replace *nth* with the actual number you want returned.